# Translate json arrays with angular ngx-translate

Tags: json, angular, ionic-framework, ngx-translate

I have a long text to be translated in an Ionic 4 app. I am using angular ngx-translate (@ngx-translate v11.0.1).

To improve readability I would like to have the translation in multiples lines instead of one.

I have changed my i18n json, from this (en-US.json):

```
  "common-questions-content" : "<b>Question 1?</b> Answer 1 <br> <b>Question 2?</b> Answer 2 <b>Question 3?</b> Answer 3",
```

To this:

```
  "common-questions-content" : [
    "<b>Question 1?</b> Answer 1 <br>",
    "<b>Question 2?</b> Answer 2 <br>",
    "<b>Question 3?</b> Answer 3"
  ],
```

Unexpectedly this works! But, **it puts commas** between every value of the array:

[image: strings separated with commas]

I load the translation service in my app.component.ts:

```
import {TranslateService} from '@ngx-translate/core';
...
private translateService: TranslateService,
...    
this.translateService.use('en-US');
```

Finally I use it in my html page like that:

```
{{ 'common_questions' | translate }}
```

Is it possible to change this behavior and just show all the text without commas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend you to have one single input per statement and without html tags int the translations such as :

in your en.JSON :

```
"QUESTION_1":"blabla",
"QUESTION_2":"blabla",
"QUESTION_3":"blabla",
"ANSWER_1":"blabla",
"ANSWER_2":"blabla",
"ANSWER_3":"blabla",
```

Then in your component, create two class properties of type array like so:

```
public questions : string[];
pulbic answers : string[];
constructor (private translate: TranslateService) {
  translate.get(["QUESTION_1", "QUESTION_2", "QUESTION_3"]).subscribe(
      values => {
        this.questions = Object.keys(values).map(key => values[key]);
      }
   );
   translate.get(["ANSWER_1", "ANSWER_2", "ANSWER_3"]).subscribe(
      values => {
        this.answers = Object.keys(values).map(key => values[key]);
      }
   );
}
```

Then in your html display, customize, add click events or whatever you need :

```
<ion-grid>
   <ion-row>
      <ion-col col-6>
         <ion-grid>
           <ion-row *ngFor="let q of questions"><b>{{q}}</b></ion-row>
         </ion-grid>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col col-6> 
         <ion-grid>
           <ion-row *ngFor="let a of answers">{{a}}</ion-row>
         </ion-grid>
      </ion-col>
   </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

This is basic html implementation, but you see how much potential is left for you to use. you can define click events, animations, colors, selected items and so on..

Answer (score 2):

A more cleaner solution which:

- avoids creating unhanded subscriptions,
- is reusable across different components

is to create a custom pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslatePipe } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'translateList',
})
export class TranslateListPipe extends TranslatePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(key: any, length: number): any[] {
    return [...Array(length).keys()].map((i) => super.transform(`${key}.${i}`));
  }
}
```

And use it like so in any template with help of `NgFor`:

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of 'TRANSLATION_KEY' | translateList:2">{{ item }}</div>
```

Where `TRANSLATION_KEY` is key that hols an array of 2 strings:

```
"TRANSLATION_KEY": ["hello", "world"]
```

This custom pipe extends `ngx-translate`'s own `TranslatePipe` and uses `super.transform(...)` call under the hood, so all translation heavy lifting is still handled by `ngx-translate`.